# What does the mode parameter do in the webpack.config.js file?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am working on a project using *Webpack*, and I happened to notice a parameter in the object called `mode`.

According to the documentation, it has two possible values (both are a `string`). One is `development`, and the other is `production`.

Below is a part of my `webpack.config.js` file.

```js
module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
};
```

I can already infer that `development` will be slower, and `production` will be faster. However, what makes the code slower in `development`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are the differences of what *Webpack* compiles your code to depending on your `mode`.

### The `development` mode

This mode uses the [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) function to execute all of your code in a string. It does not make it smaller, except for the fact that it places all of your code on one line.

The `eval()` function is slower then normal JavaScript (quote from MDN below), so it is **not recommended to use this in production**!

From MDN:

> `eval()` is also slower than the alternatives, since it has to invoke the JavaScript interpreter, while many other constructs are optimized by modern JS engines.

### The `production` mode

In `production` mode, *Webpack* will properly make your code much smaller in size (without using the `eval()` function).

***Always* use this mode in production!**

Answer (score 0):

production mode used to optimize all JS files, whereas development mode keeps the JS file as it.

Comment: Please add more information. Thanks!